# Rounding of hours in sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

The values ​​you see below are loaded with a query and they are related to a time stamp. What they ask me to insert is a rounded value; up and down. Rounding must be done at minutes of 15 and 30.

If the round is set to 15 and the marking has been made at 7:59, it is rounded off to 8:00 if the marking is at 8:01 am rounded to 8:15 am, as do I implement this thing within this query?

**Query:**

```
select Data, string_agg(Ore, '  ') as Ore 
from ( 
   select FORMAT(DataCreazione, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'it-IT') as Data,
          CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR,DataCreazione), ':', DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione)) as
Ore 
   from Marcatura 
    where IdUtente = 2
    and (Stato='Ingresso' or Stato='Uscita') 
     and cast(DataCreazione as DateTime)
        between cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '10-11-18', 5), 23)  as datetime)
            and  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '10-11-19', 5), 23)  as datetime)
) t 
group by Data 
order by CONVERT(datetime, Data, 105) desc
```

**Values:**

```
 05/07/2019 -- 14:45  19:27
 04/07/2019 -- 11:41  11:41
 07/06/2019 -- 12:39
 01/06/2019 -- 8:27  8:27  8:27  8:27
 18/04/2019 -- 15:41  15:41
 08/04/2019 -- 11:52  11:54
 01/04/2019 -- 7:25
 27/03/2019 -- 21:38  21:38
 23/03/2019 -- 13:32  13:32
 08/03/2019 -- 21:20  21:20
 04/03/2019 -- 21:48  21:48
 02/03/2019 -- 8:3  8:3
```

If the state is equal to < Ingresso > it is rounded up to the top if the status is < Uscita > is rounded down, for example 07:59 becomes 08:00 whereas if it is 17:44 it becomes 17:45

Comment: Not clear to me! What is the expected output?

Comment: Sample data to with those expected results will help us too,

Comment: for example 07:59 becomes 08:00 whereas if it is 17:44 it becomes 17:45 @Larnu

Comment: It would really help if you could show a list of datetime values and their expected rounding. Are you saying you always want to round up to the next increment of 15 minutes?

Comment: Don't post expected result or any other relevant info as comments, update your question instead. Why would 17:44 become 18:00, shouldn't it be 17:45?

Comment: *"for example 07:59 becomes 08:00 whereas if it is 17:44 it becomes 18:00 @Larnu"* those both round up; when you are rounding down?

Comment: I was wrong to write you are right 17:44 becomes 17:45 @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I have to round up when the status is Ingresso. And round down by default when it Uscita @Larnu

Comment: Where is "Ingresso" and "Uscita" coming from? I don't see that in your data or examples. We still **need** both the sample and expected result sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Logic is much more simple than described, perhaps. 
Try this approach:

EDIT: Applied logic to your own query

```
select Data, string_agg(Ore, '  ') as Ore 
from ( 
   select FORMAT(DataCreazione, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'it-IT') as Data,
          CONCAT(
          (Case
              when Datepart(MINUTE, DataCreazione) > 45
              then Datepart(hour, Datacreazione)+1
              else Datepart(hour, Datacreazione)
           end)
           ,':'
           ,(case
                 when DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione) between 0 and 15 then '15'
                 when DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione) between 16 and 30 then '30'
                 when DATEPART(MINUTE, DataCreazione) between 31 and 45 then '45'
                 else '00' end               
            )) as Ore 
   from Marcatura 
    where IdUtente = 2
    and (Stato='Ingresso' or Stato='Uscita') 
     and DataCreazione
    between cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '10-11-18', 5), 23)  as datetime)
            and  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '10-11-19', 5), 23)  as datetime)
) t 
group by Data 
order by CONVERT(datetime, Data, 105) desc;
```

SQLFiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/475202/1 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/23d16/13

Answer (score 1):

I would use `timefromparts()`:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               (case when datepart(minute, @time) not in (0, 15, 30, 45) then 15 else 0 end),
               timefromparts(datepart(hour, @time),
                             15 * floor(datepart(minute, @time) / 15.0) % 60,
                             0, 0, 0
                           )
              )
```

This is a little more complicated because you want to round up.  So the idea is to round down and then selectively add 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

this logic might help.

```
declare @time time
set @time = '14:41'

select case     
    when datepart(mi, @time) between 15 and 30 then dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, @time) + 30, @time)
    when datepart(mi, @time) between 16 and 45 then dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, @time) + 45, @time)
    when datepart(mi, @time) between 46 and 59 then dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, @time) + 60, @time)
    else dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, @time), @time) end
```

applying this in your query.

```
select Data, string_agg(Ore, '  ') as Ore 
from ( 
   select FORMAT(DataCreazione, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'it-IT') as Data,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (case    
            when datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108)) between 15 and 30 then dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))) + 30, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108)))
            when datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))) between 16 and 45 then dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))) + 45, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108)))
            when datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))) between 46 and 59 then dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))) + 60, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108)))
            else dateadd(mi, -datepart(mi, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))), CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DataCreazione,108))) end), 108)  as Ore 
   from Marcatura 
    where IdUtente = 2
    and (Stato='Ingresso' or Stato='Uscita') 
     and cast(DataCreazione as DateTime)
        between cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '10-11-18', 5), 23)  as datetime)
            and  cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, '10-11-19', 5), 23)  as datetime)
) t 
group by Data 
order by CONVERT(datetime, Data, 105) desc
```